# how to set multiple attributes at once using inner query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Suppose i have a table structure like this

```
Table_AB
=========

+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| AttrA        | AttrB        | unique_id |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| {"a","b"}    | {"c","d"}    |     25    |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Both AttrA and AttrB is jsonb columns. Now my task is to update Table_AB in such a way that the key "a" should be deleted from AttrA and the key "c" should be deleted from AttrB. The result should look like this:-

```
Table_AB
=========

+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| AttrA        | AttrB       | unique_id |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| {"b"}        | {"d"}       |    25     |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

To achieve this i have written the query like this:

```
UPDATE Table_AB
   SET AttrA = ( SELECT AttrA::jsonb #- '{a}' FROM Table_AB where unique_id= 25) ,
   SET AttrB = ( SELECT AttrB::jsonb #- '{c}' FROM Table_AB where unique_id= 25)
  FROM Table_AB where unique_id= 25;
```

I am able to get the desired output using this query. But i want to optimize this query using only one nested statement instead of two nested statements and only one statements, something like..

```
UPDATE Table_AB
   SET AttrA, AttrB = ( SELECT AttrA::jsonb #- '{a}', AttrB::jsonb #- '{c}' 
                          FROM Table_AB 
                         WHERE unique_id= 25) 
  FROM Table_AB 
 WHERE unique_id= 25;
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter update statement might be

```
UPDATE Table_AB
   SET AttrA = AttrA::jsonb #- '{a}' ,
       AttrB = AttrB::jsonb #- '{c}'
 WHERE unique_id= 25
```

which doesn't have any subquery.

**OR**

```
UPDATE Table_AB
   SET (AttrA, AttrB)=
       (AttrA::jsonb #- '{a}', AttrB::jsonb #- '{c}')
WHERE unique_id= 25
```

columns and their respective values to be set wrapped up with parantheses.

*Btw, it seems the statement in your case should be*

```
UPDATE Table_AB
   SET AttrA = ( SELECT AttrA::jsonb #- '{a}' FROM Table_AB where unique_id= 25) ,
       AttrB = ( SELECT AttrB::jsonb #- '{c}' FROM Table_AB where unique_id= 25)
 WHERE unique_id= 25
```

*which doesn't produce any error even if not the ideal case(not should be preferred).*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c9908874db1f9dee6959cd73cf876f82)</kbd>